# R: Sampling: Calib function: Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

Tags: r, sampling, calibration

I feel like this is a common issue, yet I can't seem to find an answer. I am working with a sampled dataset and attempting to calculate calibration weights against known population totals using the [Sampling package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampling/sampling.pdf). The calib function acts on a sample column or matrix (Xs), initial weights (d), and a population total (total) to calculate g-weights. Below is the first column in my dataset which yields the error:

```
 Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

Other columns also yield this error, but for simplicity sake, I've only included the first. Reproducible example below:

```
library("sampling")
# Sample
Xs = c(3793, 4505, 2272, 1126, 1839, 2060, 9077, 3174, 4013, 1673, 1299, 3981, 1770, 1059,  899, 2475, 1731, 2135,  843, 1880, 7887, 6402, 3022, 3345, 3954, 4489, 6222, 694)
Xs <- as.matrix(sapply(Xs, as.numeric))

# Initial Weights
d = rep(1, nrow(Xs))

# Population total
total = c(1616772)

g = calib(Xs, d, total, method="logit")
```

I then searched for infinite values and NaN, based on similar questions in S.O., using the following code and found nothing.

```
length(Xs)
sum(is.finite(Xs))
sum(is.nan(Xs))
length(d)
sum(is.finite(d))
sum(is.nan(d))
length(total)
sum(is.finite(total))
sum(is.nan(total))

[1] 28
[1] 28
[1] 0

[1] 28
[1] 28
[1] 0

[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 0
```

My apologies if this is elementary.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the package but I looked and the error comes from the function base::svd(). I suspected it might be an initiation problem so I tried the following and it worked:

```
library(sampling)
Xs = c(3793, 4505, 2272, 1126, 1839, 2060, 9077, 3174, 4013, 1673, 1299, 3981, 1770, 1059,  899, 2475, 1731, 2135,  843, 1880, 7887, 6402, 3022, 3345, 3954, 4489, 6222, 694)
Xs <- as.matrix(sapply(Xs, as.numeric))

# Initial Weights
d = rep(1, nrow(Xs))

# Population total
total = c(1616772)

g = calib(Xs, d, total, method="logit")
```

Be careful though! trying different initations for d gives me very different result. i.e compare to using: `d = rep(2, nrow(Xs))`.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. Good call. I didn't want to provide an initial weight to the sample (thus making d a series of 1's), but it seems as though the sample might be insufficient to calculate g-weights. I also ran it with your suggestion and got weights. For this analysis I'll have to indicate the initial weights. Thank you.